# Magento template overrides

Tags: magento, templates, magento-1.9.1

Hi everyone I want to ask if it's ok or if this is the best approach in overriding Magento Default template for frond-end. i want to override the **Widget new Product list/grid**..

#### Adding widget to Cms->page->Home page

[image]

[image]

#### And here is my front-end

[image]

Basically i want to Change the "Add to Cart" to "Select This property", And What i have done is to copy the default layout template of magento And i just set the **System->Configuration->Design**

#### Package

1. Current Package Name -> "default"

#### Themes

1. Default -> "[my module in template]"

Well This is all worked for me. but the Question is:

1. Is This a best practice?
2. Is This not critical if there is a collision between two modules overrides the same file ?